# Configure logging with Lift

Tags: scala, log4j, lift, slf4j

The Lift [wiki page](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/Logging) on logging states that a lot of setup is done automatically. Right now my problem is that I already have a running backend with its own logging configuration and a `log4j.properties` file in my classpath which should be used. There are also dependencies to log4j and SLF4j already in the classpath.

The main problem is that I get complete debug output for everything. Hibernate in particular -- which is very annoying.

I am using Lift 2.3-M1 and tried doing the following in the beginning of `boot()`:

```
Logger.setup = Full(Log4j.withFile(getClass().getResource("/props/log4j.xml")))
```

The `log4j.xml` I am currently using is quickly hacked together to simply suppress DEBUG output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration threshold="info" xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <appender name="CA" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%p] %c{2} %m%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="info"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CA"/>
  </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

When I create an errornous `log4j.xml` I also get an error from the SAXParser so it must be parsed. However I am still getting all DEBUG output. A second try was doing the following:

```
LiftRules.configureLogging = () => ()
Logger.setup = Full(Logback.withFile(getClass().getResource("/props/log4j.xml")))
```

Since I do not want to have Lift configure logging for me since the backend is already configured I would like to turn it completely off now. Oh and I also tried `LogBoot.logSetup = () => false` with no luck.

I would greatly appreciate any help on this issue.

Comment: Have you tried the mailing list? I think that would be a better venue for your question.

Comment: Posted it now also on the list. As a sidenote I also tried getting rid of all configuration and renamed log4j.xml to default.log4j.xml without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question got answered [on the Lift mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/liftweb/fvayO0t8t4o/u4cNVO_4y8MJ).

The fix is to remove the `logback` dependency and to include both `log4j` and `slf4j-log4j`. No other configuration in `boot()` is required besides a valid `default.log4j.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and came upon the following solution:

```
import net.liftweb.common.{ Empty, Logger }
import net.liftweb.http.Bootable
class BootLoader extends Bootable {
  def boot = {
    // other boot configuration ...

    // prevent Lift from messing up my log4j config                                                                                                                          
    Logger.setup = Empty
  }
}
```